# Python iteration exclude type not bool, float, int or not NoneType (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, iteration

I am trying to iterate a JSON file and its elements. The problem is that error messages are thrown if the value of the first iteration (elements) is of type bool/float/int or NoneType.

This was my try (It works for bool, float and int but throws TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable):

```
for element in json:
    if type(element) != bool \
                    and type(element) != float \
                    and type(element) != int \
                    and type(element) is not None:
    for value in json[element]:
        print(value)
```

Is there also a way to shorten the code in Python?

Comment: Bad indentation for your second for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python its common to just do it and handle any exceptions.

```
for element in json:
    try:
        for value in element:
            print(value)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Also, are you sure you want to iterate `json[element]` or did you mean to iterate over just `element` in the inner for loop?

Comment: sorry i meant iterating over element. It's not the original code i just tried to compromise it :) But the actual Problem can be solved with the correct If-Statement. But thanks i am trying this solution :)